# Think Outside the Box - A Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, word

> My prefix is like an angel,
>   Whose access to heaven's denied,
>   My infix is just like my whole,
>   Both lie on the outside.
>
> My suffix a type of recorder,
>   Who features heavily here.
>   You'll use me in the field,
>   To tell if you see clear.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My prefix is like an angel, Whose access to heaven's denied,

> [peri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peri) - a  winged spirit renowned for its beauty. Peris are described as mischievous beings, denied entry to paradise until they have completed penance.

My infix is just like my whole, Both lie on the outside.

> rim - on the ouside as is perimeter

My suffix a type of recorder, Who features heavily here.

> meter - a measuring device and also the rhythm pattern in a rhyme.

You'll use me in the field, To tell if you see clear.

> **[perimeter](https://www.college-optometrists.org/the-college/museum/online-exhibitions/virtual-ophthalmic-instrument-gallery/perimeters.html)** - a  instrument for determining the eye's field of vision.